# Application unable to start using CXF jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently struggling while starting the SpringBoot application which is using jetty server to expose different webservices.

Following is the exception I'm getting:

```
2019-05-14 22:14:42.820  INFO 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.j.InstrumentationManagerImpl     : registered org.apache.cxf:bus.id=cxf431097582,type=Bus,instance.id=431097582
2019-05-14 22:14:42.820 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'cxf'
2019-05-14 22:14:42.843 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'accountOperationsLink' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2019-05-14 22:14:42.850 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'loggingFeature'
2019-05-14 22:14:42.851 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking init method  'publish' on bean with name 'accountOperationsLink'
2019-05-14 22:14:42.853 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not find a definition for bean with id {http://service.vaslink.extlink.ers.seamless.com/}AccountOperationsLinkImplPort.jaxws-endpoint - no injection will be performed.
2019-05-14 22:14:42.853 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not find a definition for bean with id org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean - no injection will be performed.
2019-05-14 22:14:42.864  INFO 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://service.vaslink.extlink.ers.seamless.com/}AccountOperationsLinkImplService from class com.seamless.ers.interfaces.ersifextlink.ERSWSAccountOperationsLink
2019-05-14 22:14:43.036 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.j.JAXBDataBinding                  : Created JAXBContext "jar:file:/Users/muneeb/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.10-b140310.1920/jaxb-impl-2.2.10-b140310.1920.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/JAXBContextImpl.class Build-Id: 2.2.10-b140310.1920

2019-05-14 22:14:43.159 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.181 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.182 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.r.DefaultResourceManager           : resolving resource <org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2019-05-14 22:14:43.183 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.r.DefaultResourceManager           : resolving resource <null> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
2019-05-14 22:14:43.183 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cxf'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.207 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.wsdl11.JMSWSDLExtensionLoader.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.212 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.216 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingWSDLExtensionLoader.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.226 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPWSDLExtensionLoader.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.239 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.286 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.289 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyDestinationFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.293 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.299 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not determine bean name for instance of class org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.299 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.ConfigurerImpl                 : Could not find a definition for bean with id {http://service.vaslink.extlink.ers.seamless.com/}AccountOperationsLinkImplPort.http-destination - no injection will be performed.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.299 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.t.h.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory   : Creating Jetty HTTP Server Engine for port 8060.
2019-05-14 22:14:43.300  WARN 24477 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountOperationsLink': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@50fe837a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,VASLink,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory,dummyClass,VASClientImpl,ERSComponentConfig,ERSWSTransactionConfig,VASLinkConfig,topupRequestProcessor,VASPackagePurchaseRequest,menuRequestScheduler,accountOperationsLinkImpl,accountServicesLinkImpl,VASMenuRequestStrategy,loadERSTemplateWrapperPool,loggingFeature,logInbound,logOutbound,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,cxf.config0,*.http-conduit,accountOperationsLink,accountServicesLink,cxf.config1,processingService,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry,propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebSocketConfiguration,websocketContainerCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat,tomcatServletWebServerFactory,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration,servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer,tomcatServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer,server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata,webServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor,errorPageRegistrarBeanPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration,dispatcherServlet,spring.mvc-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration,dispatcherServletRegistration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration,defaultValidator,methodValidationPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration,error,beanNameViewResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$DefaultErrorViewResolverConfiguration,conventionErrorViewResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,errorAttributes,basicErrorController,errorPageCustomizer,preserveErrorControllerTargetClassPostProcessor,spring.resources-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter$FaviconConfiguration,faviconHandlerMapping,faviconRequestHandler,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,mvcContentNegotiationManager,mvcPathMatcher,mvcUrlPathHelper,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,mvcResourceUrlProvider,defaultServletHandlerMapping,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcViewResolver,mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter,defaultViewResolver,viewResolver,welcomePageHandlerMapping,requestContextFilter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,hiddenHttpMethodFilter,httpPutFormContentFilter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration,mbeanExporter,objectNamingStrategy,mbeanServer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,spring.jta-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializationConfiguration,dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerServletWebConfiguration,freeMarkerConfigurer,freeMarkerConfiguration,freeMarkerViewResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,spring.freemarker-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyWebConfiguration,groovyMarkupViewResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration,groovyMarkupConfigurer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,spring.groovy.template-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration,gsonBuilder,gson,standardGsonBuilderCustomizer,spring.gson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration,standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer,spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration,jacksonObjectMapperBuilder,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration,parameterNamesModule,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration,jacksonObjectMapper,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,jsonComponentModule,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration,stringHttpMessageConverter,spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpEncodingProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration,mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,messageConverters,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration,jacksonCodecCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,platformTransactionManagerCustomizers,spring.transaction-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionProperties,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration,restTemplateBuilder,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration$TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizerConfiguration,tomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,characterEncodingFilter,localeCharsetMappingsCustomizer,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartAutoConfiguration,multipartConfigElement,multipartResolver,spring.servlet.multipart-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MultipartProperties,org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration,payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping,soapActionAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping,annotationActionEndpointMapping,defaultMethodEndpointAdapter,soapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver,simpleSoapExceptionResolver,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration$WsConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration,messageDispatcherServlet,spring.webservices-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesProperties,cxf]; root of factory hierarchy
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter          : Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'loadERSTemplateWrapperPool'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter          : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'characterEncodingFilter'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter          : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter          : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter          : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'requestContextFilter'
2019-05-14 22:14:43.301 DEBUG 24477 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory': [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
2019-05-14 22:14:43.304  INFO 24477 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>project-base</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.seamless.meta</groupId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.seamless.ers.extlink</groupId>
    <artifactId>rw-mtn-vaslink</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>VAS Server Link </description>

    <properties>
        <seamless-common.version>2.75.0</seamless-common.version>
        <groovy-all.version>2.4.0</groovy-all.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>2.11.0</log4j.version>
        <jetm.version>1.2.3</jetm.version>
        <seamless-common-spring.version>2.18.0</seamless-common-spring.version>
        <seamless-commons-spring.version>2.14.0</seamless-commons-spring.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
        <mariadb-java-client.version>2.1.0</mariadb-java-client.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>6.0.6</mysql-connector-java.version>
        <quartz.version>1.8.4</quartz.version>
        <spring-boot-dependencies.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</spring-boot-dependencies.version>
        <spring-context-support.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring-context-support.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seamless.meta</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservice-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.seamless.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>seamless-common-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${seamless-common-spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.94.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.seamless.ers.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>ers-ws-transport</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.seamless.ers</groupId>
            <artifactId>ers-txe-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.179.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>se.seamless.ers</groupId>
            <artifactId>ers-txe-client-transport-ws</artifactId>
            <version>3.179.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seamless.ers.interfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>ersifclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-dependencies.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-context-support.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetm</artifactId>
            <version>${jetm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fm.void.jetm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetm-optional</artifactId>
            <version>${jetm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
            <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seamless.ers.interfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>ersifextlink</artifactId>
            <version>2.34.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.seamless.common</groupId>
                    <artifactId>seamless-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seamless.ers.interfaces.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>ersifplatform-internal</artifactId>
            <version>3.40.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy-all.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-commercial</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have removes `<Build>` part from `pom.xml` because I was unable to post the question. Can anybody please guide me from the logs what went wrong and why the application is unable to start.

Comment: Your dependency tree looks to be incomplete. I can't see Spring Boot on it. Can you try and update it? I'm thinking there's a version conflict with Jetty, but am unable to ascertain where/why/how without seeing the full picture!

Comment: @NotaJD I've added the full dependency tree. Please review it.

Comment: Something else is fishy - in 9.4, they removed SessionManager from Jetty (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/upgrading-jetty.html). Are you using an IDE? Would you be able to do something like an "Open Type" or "Find Type" and search for "org.eclipse.jetty.server.SessionManager" and see if it's present on your classpath elsewhere?

Comment: Also note it's the `accountOperationsLink` bean that's failing - does it or its target implementation reference `SessionManager`?

Comment: I'm using intelliJ IDE and I have created a webmethod and trying to expose it at http://0.0.0.0:8060/vaslink/services endpoint but while starting the application i'm getting this error. As far as the accountOperationsLink concerns it's just implementing the webmethods

Comment: Do you see the `SessionManager` type on your classpath anywhere?

Comment: I've shared the accountOperationLink as well in the post and no I didn't see any `SessionManager` in classpath

Comment: I've changed the debug level and updated the logs. Please take a moment to review those aswell.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml it is easier to see whats going on.

Comment: You are mixing ancient versions of Jetty (6) with newer ones. Hence your dependencies are a mess. You are also mixing jars from Spring 4.3 and 5.0 and finally you state you want to use Jetty but still tomcat is on the class path. So not sure what is going on here but a lot needs to be improved upon.

Comment: @Calixto Added the pom file but due to the post restrictions I deleted the build part from it.